# Parallel data to serial in C/C++ : Implementing a multiplex

Tags: c++, c, multiplexing, mux

I began working on the implementation of a basic parallel to serial data converter (MUX) in C or C++. Basically, this program takes data from some files and shows them in serial in a single file.

I started with this, I searched on the internet and I didn't find much information.
Is there any library that I can use? Or any suggestions or guides?
If you have some information, regardless of programming language, please share.

Comment: This question is difficult to understand/badly formed.  It's not clear what you're actually trying to do.  It sounds like you're trying to write a device driver from the title, but from your question it sounds like you're simply trying to convert the hexadecimal representation of numbers to their binary representation.  Which is it?

Comment: Sorry for the bad formed, english is not my native language. And yes, I'am trying to write a device driver.

Comment: You want the opposite functionality of `tee`, which is usually called `funnel` or something similar.

Comment: @DavidRTribble I can't find any `funnel` function. :S

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to open many files and write their contents to a single file, try something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using std::ifstream;
using std::ofstream;
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;

int main(void)
{
  // Open the files.
  ifstream file_1("file_001.bin", ios::binary);
  if (!file_1)
  {
    cerr << "Error opening first file.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  //...
  ofstream serial_file("serial_result.bin", ios::binary);
  if (!serial_file)
  {
    cerr << "Error opening serial result file.\n";
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // Read from the files
  unsigned char byte;
  while (file_1.read(&byte, 1))
  {
    // Write to serial file.
    serial_file.write(&byte, 1);
    // Read byte from next file
    file_2.read(&byte, 1);
    serial_file.write(&byte, 1);
    // Etc.
  }
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: This assumes that both files can be read back-and-forth. This won't work if one file read blocks while the other file has bytes ready to be read. This also assumes that both files are the same size. You need a more complex algorithm.

Comment: This is just a foundation.  This needs to be examined for cases where files are of different sizes and also for byte ordering.